Creating drop-down navigation menu in mobile with Wordpress twenty-twenty-four theme
I'm creating wordpress website with twenty-twenty-four theme.
I'd like to create mobile navigation like this image
my goal
But I couldn't find how to fix the theme.
now
I made the navigation using submenu. And it shows perfect in desktop.
desktop menu
Does anyone know how to create drop-down menu in mobile with twenty-twenty-four theme??

Share your code so that we can modify it for you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Super relevant question, exactly the same thing I am looking for!
Hopefully someone can give us a fix for this...

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
